# ggplot2: combining stacked plots by identifying each stack by different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some data. I would like to graph it using a stacked graph, but with each stack referring to different variables:

```
id <- c(1:10)
date <- c("May","May","May","May","May",
          "June","June","June","June","June")
locations <- c("A1a","A1b","B1","A2","B2",
               "A1","B1","A2a","A2b","B2")
data <- c(220, 350, 377, 655, 740, 
          615, 760, 480, 179, 560)
df <- data.frame(id,date,locations,data)

library(ggplot2)
```

This was as close as I could get.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=data, fill=locations)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack")
```

I would like A1a stacked with B1, A1b stacked with B1 and A2 stacked with B2 next to each other for May; and A1 stacked with B1, A2a stacked with B2 and A2b stacked with B2 for June. Each month will have 3 bars and each bar will be a stack of 2 variables that I have specified. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no A1a, A1b, A2a, A2b in your df. Also, I'm assuming you want y = data, not y = date.

Comment: @EricWatt Opps forgot to update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have correctly understood your question.
Here is an attempt to find a solution. Hope it can help you.

```
id <- c(1:10)
date <- c("May","May","May","May","May",
          "June","June","June","June","June")
locations <- c("A1a","A1b","B1","A2","B2",
               "A1","B1","A2a","A2b","B2")
data <- c(220, 350, 377, 655, 740, 
          615, 760, 480, 179, 560)
df <- data.frame(id,date,locations,data)

df$date <- factor(df$date, levels=c("May","June"))
df1 <- cbind(df[c(1,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,9,10),],
             grp=factor(rep(c(1:3),each=2)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1, aes(x=grp, y=data, fill=locations)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "stack")+
  facet_grid(.~date)
```

[image]